# allow user to customize settings in installed slack app

Tags: slack

I'm developing a slack app, and I'd like to allow the users who uses my app to customize specific settings, e.g. 3rd-party integration passwords.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you app needs to manage custom user settings you need to build that yourself.

- UI to show and modify settings
- Storage to store settings

You can use any approach for that, e.g. build the UI part within Slack (a Slack Dialog would work nicely) or make an external website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store state of the user settings someplace. I agree with Erik that you can build the UX within slack.

I don't think Slack has a great way to do store state right now, though I suppose you could create some hacky way of doing it (create a private slack channel for each user with a random name and store state in there).

I'd suggest using either a real database, or a service like Transposit (full disclosure, I work there). With the former, you could use something like Heroku Postgres, and host an API on Heroku. With the latter, you could use the [Slack API](https://www.transposit.com/docs/references/connectors/slack-documentation/?c=so) combined with [Dynamodb](https://www.transposit.com/docs/references/connectors/aws-dynamodb-documentation/?c=so) or some other database.